# Upgrading gradle 4.5 to 7.2, throws error Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal

Tags: gradle, java-8

I am upgrading gradle 4.5 to 7.2. on build.gradle it throws exception "Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer." on line 118. The code at line 118 is as follows.

```
publishing {
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username=mvn_user
            password=mvn_pass
        }
        
        if (version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
            url snapshotRepo
            println "Publishing to ${snapshotRepo}"
        }
        else {
            url releaseRepo
            println "Publishing to ${releaseRepo}"
        }
    }
}

publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        
        artifactId = mavenArtifactId 

        from project(':server').components.java
        
        artifact project(':server').javadocJar
        artifact project(':server').sourceJar
        artifact examplePropertiesArtifact
        artifact exampleLog4jFileArtifact
        artifact windowsScriptFile
        artifact linuxScriptArtifact
        artifact aixScriptArtifact
```

Comment: Why are you publishing `server` project in another project?  Why not move the publication code to the `server` module?  You shouldn't access another project's components like this: `project(':server').components.java`. Please read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html

Answer (score 0):

[`MavenPublication`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) should work with Gradle 7.x ...while it might not know about:

```
from project(':server').components.java
```

There was [a change](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:deferred_configuration) in Gradle 4.8, which requires to wrap with: `afterEvaluate {}`:

> Prior to Gradle 5.0, the `publishing {}` block was (by default) implicitly treated as if all the logic inside it was executed after the project is evaluated. This behavior caused quite a bit of confusion and was deprecated in Gradle 4.8, because it was the only block that behaved that way.

Comment: server has seperate build.gradle file

Comment: Which part of code needs to be in afterEvaluate block?

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin `java-library` instead of `java` as gradle have change java plugin to java-library plugin

apply plugin: 'java-library'